# Can the Woodbury identity be bounded for inverse of matrix plus identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, upper-lower-bounds, covariance, symmetric-matrices

Based on the [Woodbury identify][1] we know that:

$(A + B)^{-1}$ = $A^{-1} - A^{-1}(AB^{-1} + I)^{-1}$

It can also be shown that if $B$ is PSD,

$(A + B)^{-1} \leqslant A^{-1}$

Therefore if $B = cI$,

$(A + cI)^{-1} \leqslant A^{-1}$

This is a fairly weak bound, so Im wondering if we can somehow create a tighter bound that uses information in $B$ such as $c$ when $B = cI$. For example when $B-cI$, the Woodbury identify can be re-arrange as follows, but not sure if this helps..

$(A + B)^{-1}$ = $A^{-1}(cA^{-1} + I)^{-1}$

Any help to tighten these two bounds, both when $B$ is any PSD matrix, and when $B=cI$ would be appreciated.

Comment: Woodbury gives you $(A - B)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}B(I + A^{-1}B)^{-1}A^{-1}$, which is not the formula that you came up with

Comment: Your question is a bit strange. Consider the scalar case. What upper bound of $\dfrac{1}{a+c}$ are you expecting? Apart from $\dfrac{1}{a}$ and $\dfrac{1}{c}$, the only “natural” bound that comes to mind is $\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{ac}}$, by $AM\ge GM$. Its matrix analogue is $\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{c}}A^{-1/2}$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann This is just another form of the same identity, see here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity

Comment: @user1551 Thanks, this is sort of what I was looking for, I guess the caveat is that the bound then gets looser both as c goes lower than 1, but also greater.

Comment: @user1551 Whereas $1/a$ gets tighter as c tends to 0.